# How to write a custom aggregation function for strings?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, pandas, anaconda

I have a Dataframe of millions of records, i'm trying to make the whole dataframe to be grouped by one column 'napciente', that is done. But there are 63 columns which i need to aggregate as string based on a specific match, for example, if the Series contain "SI" and any other strings i want to return that "SI" as my result of the aggregation.

[image]

so i need to define my own aggregation that finds the string in the series and returns it. here i'm only posting data for 1 group and truncated columns

```
data.groupby('npaciente')['asistencia'].apply(lambda x: if x.str.find("SI"): return "SI")
```

The above is invalid, suggestions?

Comment: Are all of the match conditions going to be the same?

Comment: No they change depending on the column

Answer (score 1):

You can use `apply` directly on the `groupby` object, then in the custom function, just return `pd.Series` in order for pandas to refer to it as columns:

```
def agg_func(group):
    """group is actually a dataframe containing only the relevant rows"""
    result = {}
    if group["asistencia"].str.find("SI").any()
        result["asistencia"] = "SI"
    return pd.Series(result)

data.groupby('npaciente').apply(agg_func)
```

Of course, you need to add more logic to `agg_func` in order for it to do what you want it to do.